# Must the variadic arguments be the second parameter in a variadic function?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, variadic-functions

Debugging this code, I find the parameter "size" in the first position of my array structure.

Must the variadic arguments of a variadic function always be passed as the second parameter? In the code below, I commented my fix, which consists in skipping the first va_list value (and it worked):

```
void my_array_assign(struct my_array * array, int size, ...)
{
    va_list arguments_pointer;                                                                          
    int i;                                                                                              
    my_array_create(array, size);

    va_start(arguments_pointer, size);                                                          
    va_arg(arguments_pointer, int); // MyFix: do I really have to skip first parameter "size" here ?

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        array->data[i] = va_arg(arguments_pointer, int);
    }

    va_end(arguments_pointer);
}
```

I could not find the answer anywhere, because all the examples I found use just two parameters: the size, and the variadic arguments.

This is where I call the function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    my_array test;

    my_array_init(&test);

    my_array_assign(&test, 3, 0, 1, 2);  // the call

/* ETC... */
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many library examples exist with more than 1 fixed parameters like `int sprintf(char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);`.

Answer (score 4):

No, variadic functions in C can have an arbitrary but defined amount of fixed argument in first positions (but at least one fixed argument is required). See e.g. [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) as an example. And read carefully [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html).

I have a code in [main.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/blob/master/main.c) of my MELT monitor, the function `mom_debugprintf_at` line 104 (of commit [a37e36c...](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/commit/a37e36c9e4121c7c45ae49f19c66c895d1365de4)), it has 4 fixed arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why my fix works? Could it be a compiler issue? (Unfortunately, I'm using VS2010)

Comment: Use a debugger to find out. BTW, consider installing Linux, using `gcc -Wall -g` to compile and `gdb` to debug.

Comment: If only I could. Project specs. -_- I'm updating the question including the function call.

Comment: Note: As I recall, early C even allowed variadic functions with no fixed arguments.  Not having that ability today is not much of a loss.

Comment: @chux: You can still declare a function as `int foo()` to leave the args unspecified, then call `foo("abc", 0);` and `foo(1, 2, 3, 0);` from the same compilation unit.  That doesn't help you *define* it in C, I don't think, but it lets you call a fully-variadic function written in asm, like in this code-golf answer: [How many arguments were passed?](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162097)

Comment: @PeterCordes [Interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649371/must-the-variadic-arguments-be-the-second-parameter-in-a-variadic-function/25649411?noredirect=1#comment86643107_25649411).  I see, with your idea, how modern code could still effectively have a `int foo(...)`.  Of course some [back channel](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/back-channel) is needed to determine the argument list.

Comment: @chux: yeah, as I said in my code-golf answer I linked, it could make sense if passing pointers to "boxed" objects, if that's the right term.  A NULL terminator for the arg list like in `execl(3)` to mark the end of args then becomes a valid sentinel / terminator, if the other args have to be valid pointers.  I think that's a plausible justification for that calling convention :P

Comment: @PeterCordes Aside: A `NULL` terminator for `int foo(const char *path, const char *arg, ...)` is trouble for highly _portable_ code.   It can be UB with `foo(".", "hello", NULL);` versus the more reliable `foo(".", "hello", (void*)NULL);`.  Since `NULL`, the _null pointer constant_, may be an integer type or `void*`, `foo(".", "hello", NULL);` lacks a conversion to pointer should `NULL` be some integer.  See last part of [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Null-Pointer-Constant.html)

Comment: @chux: Oh right, `0` is a valid definition of `NULL`.  I was talking about an asm calling convention (ABI), but good point that you might have to write different C source to make sure the caller compiles to asm that passes the binary representation of a NULL pointer.  Potentially problematic on platforms where `int` is smaller than `void*` and high garbage is allowed in arg-passing slots.  x86-64 SysV is like that, but IDK if any compilers define NULL as `0` instead of `((void*)0)` or something.